# Java 8 - How to search a MultiValueMap with value?

Tags: java, spring, collections, java-8

I have a

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
```

The type of value is a list of strings:

```
List<String> valueList = map.get('key');
```

How can i search through this map (through all the valueLists within this map) and get all the values which startsWith 'xy' in a list back?

I hope the question is clear.

I have tried this, but no success:

```
  map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e-> e.getValue().stream().filter(value -> value.startsWith(searchString)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get this error: Stream cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: `map with single values` meaning a `List` where size == 1?

Comment: sorry.. no.. lists can have many values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly:

```
map.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .filter(x -> x.startsWith(searchString))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: but you just check the first elements of list, which also have exactly 1 value. I want to search ALL values in ALL lists. Lists can also have many values.. a typical MultiValueMap

Comment: @akcasoy didn't you say yourself: *How can i search this map with single values*?

Comment: @akcasoy so you want to search across all values, right?

Comment: i have reformulated my question

Comment: @akcasoy and I did my answer

Comment: thank you.. do u know how i can at the end filter the duplicates ?

Comment: ok. toSet() instead of toList helped ;)